# How to change a sprite (ui.image.sprite) and delete the previous one from RAM

Tags: unity-game-engine, ram, unity-ui

I need to take a screenshot of the screen and put it as a sprite in the image component.
I do it with this code:

```
public Texture2D TakeScreenshot()
{
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0,0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
texture.Apply();
return texture;
}
```

```
screenShot = screenshotHandler.TakeScreenshot();
image.sprite = Sprite.Create(screenShot, new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), Vector2.zero);
```

The entire screen is filled with multi-colored random pixels, so the screenshot weighs about 15MB.
I need to do this code multiple times and I noticed with the memory profiler that the previous screenshots are not removed from RAM. As a result, I have one final screenshot, and many screenshots in RAM that I don't need. What do I need to do to remove them?

RAM is extremely important in an game
[Untitled files are screenshots. I took more and less screenshots, I know for sure that they are screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjrnf.png)

I tried using image.overrideSprite instead of image.sprite but screenshots stay in memory too

Comment: How about `UnityEngine.Object.Destroy`???

Comment: I tried ```Destroy(image.sprite);``` before taking a new screenshot, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I realized that the profiler says "Texture2D", but I thought about the sprite.
Now my code looks like this:

```
Destroy(screenShot);
screenShot = screenshotHandler.TakeScreenshot();
image.sprite = Sprite.Create(screenShot, new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), Vector2.zero);
```

Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: i had given it some thought and was going to suggest that in the method you keep in the class a handle on the texture and destroy it before making a new one